# Joint essential range of $\varphi\in L^\infty(X,\mu)^d$.

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

**Definition:** Let $(X,\mu)$ be a measure space and $\phi=(\phi_1,\cdots,\phi_d)\in L^{\infty}(X)$. The joint essential range of $\phi$ is the set $\mathcal{C}(\phi)$ which is consisting of all $z = (z_1,\cdots,z_d)\in \mathbb{C}^d$ such that for every $\varepsilon>0$
$$\mu \left(\left\{t\in X\,;\;\sum_{i=1}^d|\phi_i(t)-z_i|<\varepsilon  \right\}\right)>0 .$$

> Assume that 
>   $$r=\max\left\{\sum_{i=1}^d|z_i|^2; (z_1,\cdots,z_d)\in \mathcal{C}(\phi)\right\}.$$
>   i.e. 
>   $$ r:=\max\left\{\sum_{i=1}^d|z_i|^2\,;\;\mu \left(\left\{t\in X\,;\;\sum_{i=1}^d|\phi_i(t)-z_i|<\varepsilon  \right\}\right)>0,\;\text{for every}\;\varepsilon>0\right\}.$$
>   I want to understand why the following two facts hold?
>   $$\mu \left(\left\{t\in X\,;\;\sum_{i=1}^d|\phi_i(t)|^2>r \right\}\right)=0 ,$$
>   and
>   $$ \int_X\left(\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^d|\phi_k|^2\right)|f|^2d\mu\leq r  \int_X|f|^2d\mu.$$

Note that the two facts figure in [this paper](https://msp.org/pjm/1981/95-1/pjm-v95-n1-p03-s.pdf) (page 6 and 7).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that by definition, 
$
z=(z_1,\ldots,z_d)\notin \mathcal{C}(\phi),
$ if and only if there exists a neiborhood $U_z$ of $z$ such that
$$
\mu\left(\{t\in X\;|\;\phi(t)\in U_z\}\right) =0.
$$ We can see that if $w\in U_z$, then $w$ has a neighborhood that satisfies the above condition, namely $U_z$. This implies that $w\notin\mathcal{C}(\phi)$ for all $w\in U_z$, i.e. $U_z \subset \Bbb C^d\setminus \mathcal{C}(\phi).$ From this, it follows that $$\Bbb C^d\setminus\mathcal{C}(\phi)=\bigcup_{z\notin\mathcal{C}(\phi)}U_z.$$ We can see that $\mathcal{C}(\phi)$ is closed, and since $r:=\max\limits_{\lambda \notin \cup_z U_z}|\lambda|^2=\max\limits_{\lambda \in \mathcal{C}(\phi)}|\lambda|^2$ is a bounded constant, it  is contained in $$B(0,\sqrt{r})=\{(z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_d)\in\Bbb C^d\;|\;|z|^2=\sum_j |z_j|^2\le r\}.$$ This establishes that $\mathcal{C}(\phi)$ is compact. Since $\Bbb C^d\setminus\mathcal{C}(\phi)$ is a second-countable space as a subspace of $\Bbb C^d$, there exists a countable family $\{z_i\}$ such that
$$
\Bbb C^d\setminus\mathcal{C}(\phi)=\bigcup_{i\in\Bbb N}U_{z_i}.
$$ This gives
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\mu\left(\left\{t\in X\;\big|\;\sum_k |\phi_k(t)|^2>r\right\} \right)&\le& \mu\left(\left\{t\in X\;\big|\;\phi(t)\notin\mathcal{C}(\phi)\right\} \right)\\&\le&\mu\left(\bigcup_{i\in\Bbb N}\left\{t\in X\;\big|\;\phi(t)\in U_{z_i}\right\} \right)\\
&\le&\sum_{i\in\Bbb N}\mu\left(\left\{t\in X\;\big|\;\phi(t)\in U_{z_i}\right\} \right)=0.
\end{eqnarray}$$ This in turn implies that $$
\sum_k |\phi_k(t)|^2\le r
$$ for $\mu$-almost every $t\in X$. This gives
$$
\int_X\left(\displaystyle\sum_{k}|\phi_k(t)|^2\right)|f(t)|^2d\mu(t)\leq r  \int_X|f(t)|^2d\mu(t).
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please explain me more your first paragraph ''Observe that $\mathcal{C}(\phi)$ is a closed subset of $B(0,\sqrt{r})=\{(z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_d)\in\Bbb C^d\;|\;\sum_j |z_j|^2\le r\}$, and that by definition, if
$
z=(z_1,\ldots,z_d)\notin \mathcal{C}(\phi),
$ then there exists a neiborhood $U_z$ of $z$ such that
$$
\mu\left(\{t\in X\;|\;\phi(t)\in U_z\}\right) =0.
$$'' Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you for the details. I don't understand what you mean ''we can take $U_w$ as $U_z$''? Also I think that you mean ''$\mathcal{C}(\phi)$ is compact and thus ..''

Comment: @Student I've revised some parts of my answer. I hope it is better now.

Comment: I think we should write $UT_kU^*f=\varphi_kf$ for all $f\in L^2(\mu)$ and $k=1,\cdots,d$. Or we can write
$$T_kf\equiv\varphi_kf,$$
because we identify $H$ to $L^2(X)$.

Comment: Surely, you are right. Sometimes, some authors allow abuse of the notation if there is little possibility of confusion.

Comment: Please my last question: I revise again the answer, I don't understand very well why $\Bbb C^d\setminus\mathcal{C}(\phi)$ is countable? Is it because $\Bbb C^d$ is countable and $\mathcal{C}(\phi)$ is compact? Thanks

Comment: The equality $$\Bbb C^d\setminus\mathcal{C}(\phi)=\bigcup_{z\notin\mathcal{C}(\phi)}U_z=\bigcup_{i\in\Bbb N}U_{z_i},$$ holds since $\Bbb C^d\setminus\mathcal{C}(\phi)$ is countable. But I don't understand very well the argument that makes $\Bbb C^d\setminus\mathcal{C}(\phi)$ be countable. Thanks.

Comment: @Student  It is a result of a proposition saying that if $X$ is second-countable, i.e. has a countable base, then for any family of open sets $U_\alpha$, there's a countable subfamily $U_{\alpha_i}$ such that $\bigcup_\alpha U_\alpha = \bigcup_i U_{\alpha_i}$. It is a topological result. And in fact, one should say $\Bbb C^d$ is "second"-countable.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know it.

Comment: Why then you have shown that $\mathcal{C}(\phi)$ is closed?thank  you very much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88471/discussion-between-song-and-student).

Comment: Please is $
\Bbb C^d\setminus\mathcal{C}(\phi)$ is also a second-countable set? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Student Yes, since it is an open subset of $\Bbb C^d$!

Comment: I think we don't need to show that it is open because Every subspace of a second-countable space is second-countable.
Please see the link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-countable_space

Comment: @Student Oh, you are right. Sorry for the confusion.